# What software would I use for programming an LED electronic sign over Serial (RS252)?

Tags: serial-port, led

I'm attempting to program an old electronic sign, but the manufacturer doesn't have any information, the model number online returns next to nothing, and as far as software options online go, I'm unsure. Would anyone know how to push to this thing? (Pictures show model info, cable connection, etc.[image]enter image description here[image]

I tried using a software called message editor  but it never ends up detecting the sign.